# How to read input from the end of printed line in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

```clj
(println "The number is: " (read-line))
```

`(read-line)` reads coming input from a new line.

How to read from the end of printed string instead of a newline?

Like in C:

```c
printf("The number is: ")
scanf("%d", &value)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you do the `(read-line)` inside the print it will be executed first (blocks and waits for the user-input, then the "question" and the user input will be printed).

Instead you have to first print, then flush (to make sure, the output is visible), finally read the input.

```clj
(do
  (print "The number is: ")
  (flush)
  (read-line))
; The number is: 666
; ⇒ "666"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but my question is not about it. My question is about how to read user's input not from a new line but from the same line where string were printed by (println) function. Like that: 

```clojure
    "This number is "   ;reads here 
```

Comment: @Khatry I have adjusted the answer

Comment: Thank you. With (flush) it works.
I already thought I would need to delve into Java.Reader or something.

Comment: @cfrick Why is the `do` needed to "execute multiple things one after another"? Isn't that supposed to be case anyway?

Comment: @rmoestl No, it's not.  And I see how this could be misinterpreted.
It's in the answer to give a better REPL experience with the snippet (no
interweaving of REPL-input and outputs).